# Cómo insertar un vector en una posición determinada de una matriz bidimensional

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Tengo una matriz bidimensional `[3x3]` de la forma:

```
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

y quiero añadir vectores en determinadas posiciones de dicha matriz, de la forma:

```
[[[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

los cuales contienen el mismo valor de la posición dada, pero en las dos posiciones del vector, manteniendo las filas correspondientes...

Si hago lo siguiente:

```
matriz = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
matriz_2 = [[v, v] for vv in matriz for v in vv]
print(matriz_2)
```

El valor devuelto es:

```
[[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Que aplana la matriz, en vez de mantener el formato de filas independientes.

¿Alguna idea de cómo conseguir que se mantengan las filas...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mantener la estructura tienes que aplicar una función a cada vector de la matriz

p.e:

```
def doblar (L):
    res=[]
    for x in L:
        res+= [[x,x]]
    return res
```

que es lo mismo que:

```
def doblar2 (L):
    return [[v, v]  for v in L]
```

si lo juntamos todo:

```
nm=  [ doblar2(vv) for vv in matriz ]
nm= [[[v, v]  for v in vv] for vv in matriz]
```

tenemos la solución.